# Нужна ли запятая после "а еще"?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

Предложение "А еще я желаю вам оставаться в душе немного детьми". Нужна ли запятая после "а еще" и где она еще нужна или нет в этом предложении? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ни в коем случае! Никаких запятых не нужно!